# Tree interval representation in python

Tags: python, tree, networkx

Consider I have a tree built with

```
import networkx as nx
dg = nx.DiGraph()
dg.add_edges_from([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e')])
```

I want an interval representation of the following tree, what I mean is

```
[1, [2, [3, 4], [5, 6], 7], [8,9 ], 10]
```

Where the nesting corresponds to the tree.

Are there any functions in networkx or in an other library that allow to do this?

Comment: How do you decide the root ? Do you pick it at random ?

Comment: It's an ordered tree so the root is the min

Comment: Sorry I missed the `DiGraph`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will find a lib which do that. However it's easy with a DFS. Here is a recursive implementation:

```
def tree(dg):
    def walk(root, start):
        children = dg.successors(root)
        if children:
            cur = start+1
            res = [start]
            for c in children:
                l = walk(c, cur)
                res.append(l)
                cur = l[-1]+1
            res.append(cur)
            return res
        else:
            return [start, start+1]

    roots = [i for i in dg.nodes() if dg.in_degree(i) == 0]
    assert(len(roots) == 1)
    root = roots[0]

    return walk(root, 1)
```

Then:

```
>>> tree(dg)
[1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6], [7, 8], 9], 10]
```

By the way, you did notice that my answer is not the same as yours. You didn't specify any ordering on the children. If you want to, just sort the children list according to the desired ordering.

Comment: Thanks, I needed it to represent each node as a couple for example a = (1, 10), b = (2, 7), do you think are more direct way to do it without passing for this intermediate step?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Using the same method, you can return a dictionary `'a' : (1,10)` instead of appending to a list as I do.

Comment: Sorry I did not read well the code infact it's enough to add few lines     
dg.node[root]['born_right'] = cur
dg.node[root]['born_left'] = start
dg.node[root]['born_right'] = start + 1